# how to use when condition in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the part of the script:

```
- name: To Display SPLUNK Status

  shell: service splunk status | grep PID

  register: STATUS



- name: Showing SPLUNK Status

  debug: var=STATUS.stdout_lines



- name: Getting Process IDs of the SPLUNK

  shell: ps -ef|grep -i splunk

  register: pids_of_SPLUNK



- name: Printing the process IDs obtained

  debug: var=pids_of_SPLUNK.stdout_lines



#- name: SPLUNK is NOT running

- debug: msg="Splunk is NOT running"

  when: not STATUS.stat.exists



#- name: SPLUNK is Running

- debug: msg="Splunk is Restarted and Running"
```

that line getting me the error:  when: not STATUS.stat.exists

when splunk is running it has the status:

Splunk status:

splunkd is running (PID: 7198).

splunk helpers are running (PIDs: 7200).

When splunk is not running:

Splunk status:

splunkd is not running.

how I can use:   when   condition for it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data). For example

```
  vars:

    my_services:
      - 'splunk'
      - 'apache2'
      - 'ssh'

  tasks:

    - service_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "Service {{ item }} is not available."
      loop: "{{ my_services }}"
      when: item not in ansible_facts.services.keys()|list

    - debug:
        msg: "Service {{ item }} is available."
      loop: "{{ my_services }}"
      when: item in ansible_facts.services.keys()|list

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is {{ ansible_facts.services[item].state }}"
      loop: "{{ my_services }}"
      when: item in ansible_facts.services.keys()|list
```

give

```
    "msg": "Service splunk is not available."
    "msg": "Service apache2 is available."
    "msg": "Service ssh is available."
    "msg": "apache2 is stopped"
    "msg": "ssh is running"
```

Comment: can I use it in combination with ansible_facts    ?